# Pasar un dato de una vista por href a otra vista con method post

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Estoy aprendiendo laravel para un trabajo en la universidad con mis compañeros, ellos tienen más experiencia en el lenguaje pero ninguno me pudo explicar como hacer esto

Tengo un dato en una vista que quiero enviar a otra para llenar un espacio en un formulario

El codigo de la primera vista es este:

```
<tbody>
  @foreach($areas as $area)
  <tr>
    <td>{{ $area -> COD_AREA}} </td>
    <td>{{ $area -> NOMBRE_AREA}} </td>
    <td>{{ $area -> DESC_AREA}} </td>
    <td>
        <div class="text-center">
          <h4>
            <a href='{{ route('subarea.create',$area->NOMBRE_AREA) }}' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Registar Subarea">
              <i class="fas fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div> 
    </td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Y el codigo de la segunda vista es este:

```
<div>
{!! Form::open(['route'=>'subarea.store','method'=>'POST']) !!}
.....
<div class="form-group row">
    {!! Form::label('NOMBRE_AREA','Nombre del area al que pertenece',['class'=>'col-sm-2 col-form-label']) !!}
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {!! Form::text('NOMBRE_AREA', $area, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    </div>    
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Si la ruta es `store` ? ¿Por qué envía los datos? creo que deberían inicializar los valores en blanco los componentes del formulario  ya que pretende un nuevo registro, si fuese actualizar sería lo correcto. ¿Solo ese dato desea mostrar o la descripción también ? ¿Qué proceso hará en la segunda vista?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defines el parámetro en la ruta para que reciba el dato:

```
Route::get('miruta/{area}', 'miControlador@showForm');
```

En el controlador recibes el dato y simplemente lo pasas a la vista:

```
public function showForm($area) {

   // ...

    return view('mivista', compact('area'));
}
```

Y en la vista debería servirte el código que tienes:

```
{!! Form::text('NOMBRE_AREA', $area, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder y me funciono en parte, el unico problema ahora es que en lugar de enviar el nombre del area me llena el espacio con la palabra create, ¿estoy haciendo algo mal?

Comment: Probablemente, depende lo que estés haciendo.

Comment: Pues parece que esta guardando el nombre de la vista, porque la ruta que se genera en el href es 127.0.0.1/subarea/create?nombre del area y esta agarrando el create en lugar del nombre

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, ya lo solucione ^^